# DataGridView White Space After Last Column Header

Tags: .net, datagridview, header, paint

I'm trying to mimic what every other tabular view does with the DataGridView control, but I can't seem to get the headers correct.

I want a blank header to the right of all headers, that does not move, and is not actually a header.  Is there a way to paint the default header along the top?

Basically, this is my problem:

[image: Problem]

Comment: +1 for linking to a screen shot. I wish more people did this. A picture is worth 1K words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("a")
dt.Columns.Add("b")
dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())
dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())
dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())
dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())
dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())
dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())
dt.Columns.Add(" ")
dt.AcceptChanges()
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.AutoSize = True
DataGridView1.Columns(2).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
DataGridView1.Columns(2).Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False
```

Comment: +1, I'd suggest the same. Just add a column with no HeaderText and the AutoSizeMode set to Fill.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't answer your question, an alternative could be to set the [`AutoSizeColumnsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode.aspx) to **Fill**.

Comment: This does work, but if I have a lot of columns (in this case I do) The fill option doesn't really work too well.  I need to be able to scroll.  I've also tried setting the very last column to "Fill", but then you have to dynamically set the minimum size.  This still is not how I've seen most table controls work

Answer (score 0):

After adding all your columns, you can add an extra column, set the following properties to:

```
 AutoSizeMode = Fill;
 HeaderText = ""
 ReadOnly = true;
 SortMode = NotSortable;
```

, handle the `gridView CellPainting event` for this particular column by preventing the borders from being painted:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
                                         DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
     {
         e.AdvancedBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
         e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
         e.Handled = true;
     }
 }
```

and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best (and most efficient) way to do this is by **creating an extra column** at the end, to allow it to "eat up" (or "**take up") the space that isn't occupied** by other columns. The way to do this is to set the ***AutoSizeMode* property to *Fill***.

Here is some sample code:

```
DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
DataTable data = new DataTable();

//add columns, rows, etc. to DataTable data
data.Columns.Add("This is the first column."); data.Rows.Add(data.NewRow());
//etc.

//Add EXTRA column:

data.Columns.Add(""); //blank header

//Save changes

data.AcceptChanges();

//Set datasource
grid.DataSource = data;
```

Now, you have the grid, with an extra blank column.
**We have to set the column to the right properties:**

```
data.Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill; //Sets AutoSizeMode to fill, as explained above, for 2nd column
```

Also, as najameddine explained, you might want to set the following properties:

> ReadOnly = true;
>
> SortMode =
> NotSortable;

Essentially, you're creating a blank column that takes up the empty space.

P.S. I just noticed that surajitkhamrai has a very similar code sample, but mine is in C# - however, the concept stays the same.