# DataGridView last column cannot be resized wider

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Long story short, I ran into the same issue as [DataGridView resizeable columns, but last column can't be resized bigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951364/datagridview-resizeable-columns-but-last-column-cant-be-resized-bigger). As long as the total width of all columns exceeds the width of the control, I cannot resize the last column to make it wider, even though there is already a horizontal scrollbar. The other columns can be made wider, and the widths of succeeding columns won't change (thus making the total width of all columns wider).

One workaround is to shrink all the other columns so that the total width is less than the width of the control, grow the last column to the width I want, then grow the other columns back. But obviously this is very tedious and limited.

Another workaround I tried is to add a dummy column after the last (like suggested in answers of [DataGridView White Space After Last Column Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500061/datagridview-white-space-after-last-column-header)). However, although the now second-to-last column can grow now, it cannot go very far - it is still limited by the right border of the control. I can either make the empty column wide and appear ugly, or I can make it narrow, in which case I need multiple "goes" to widen the last column to the width I want, which is even more tedious.

I think the other question is not satisfactorily answered. The answer only gives a logical reason why this may happen, but provides no solution/good workaround. And like the other question's OP says in the comment, most grids we use don't suffer from this problem: you can drag the right border of the column beyond the right border of the control. It seems that it's only the WinForms DataGridView that suffers from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ColumnWidthChanged` event to detect that last column is resized by the user and than create margin that will give the user the feeling and functionality to resize more.
 please check the code I written below.
 its working as expected **but you will have to add your own custom horizontal scroll bar** in order to scroll the datagridview (its should be simple, the datagridview width will be affected from the custom scroll bar value).

 note that `ColumnWidthChanged` event is removed in each time the event is raised in order to prevent stackoverflow, and the event is added again after the width change.

```
private void dgvMain_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsLoading == true)
        return;

    if (e.Column.Index == dgvMain.Columns.Count-1) 
    {
        dgvMain.ColumnWidthChanged -= dgvMain_ColumnWidthChanged;
        if (dgvMain.Width - GetTotalColumnsWidth() <= 200)
        {
            e.Column.Width = e.Column.Width + 20;
            dgvMain.Width = dgvMain.Width + 40;
        }
        dgvMain.ColumnWidthChanged += new DataGridViewColumnEventHandler(dgvMain_ColumnWidthChanged);
    }
}

private int GetTotalColumnsWidth()
{
    var result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dgvMain.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        result += dgvMain.Columns[i].Width;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and I still cannot change the width in one go; instead I have to do it in increments of 40. I think that makes this solution/workaround worse than the empty column method, which as I mentioned is still too annoying for me.